# Screentime time limits for always allowed apps

Tags: screen-time

I want to limit myself to 20 minutes per day on the Kindle app. I have a downtime limit from 6pm but still want to be able to read after that time. For that reason I've set up Kindle as always allowed and also added an app limit of 20 minutes.

However, I find that the app time limit doesn't work. I see an alert 5 minutes before cutoff saying that I only have 5 minutes left. But after 5 minutes, nothing happens. I can still use the app.

Any tips?